# My Anchor link won't start at top of page

Tags: html, angularjs

I am unsure what is going. I have two footers. One footer is a sidebar, and my other footer is a regular footer on the bottom of the page. My anchor tag in my  bottom footer, that links to my about page, takes me to the bottom of the page instead of starting at the top, and my anchor tag in my sidebar footer takes me to the middle of the page! Other Anchor Links are taking me also to the middle or random parts of the pages when loaded.

I am not using anything special with the anchor. I don't think...

Here is my anchor for both footers:

```
<a href="/about" class="a-color">
    <small>About</small>
</a>
```

My pages are loaded with ng-view. I am **not** using `$anchorScroll`

Comment: @PankajParkar What do you mean to get that div shown? When I do href="#about", it takes me to www.mybusiness.com/#about. The page does not load when it does that

Comment: Sorry I missed readed the question..I thought you wanted to $anchorScroll..could you add you route configuration code please?

Comment: oh ok, no I am not using $anchorScroll

Comment: Can you post your html and js or create a fiddle to illustrate the issue?

Comment: @KAD there are too many files, directives, pages, and javascripts to list it all out. I also don't think it is a problem with my actual code. I can tell you that if you type out the website url, it will take you to the top of the page. It is just when you click the links on the website that it takes you to different parts of the page. I am almost sure this has something to do with Angular(not my code), I just do not know what.

Comment: Is the website online? Can you provide a link for your website?

Comment: @AustinPerez I am not able to reach your website. I am getting the SORRY page.

Comment: @AustinPerez i fixed the same issue by always moving the scroll position to top on route change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. It will always takes page to top on window load.

```
 $(window).load(function(){
        if (location.hash) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          }, 1);
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

ngView retains the scroll position when you navigate from one page to another. once view loaded then can use $anchorScroll to change viewport  or can add `autoscroll="true"` to ng-view element

```
<div class="ng-view" autoscroll="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly, your browser has an issue. 
1. Which browser you are facing this on? 
2. Did you try on any other browser? 
3. Is this code running fine on any other machine?
4. Did you clear cache/cookies and tried again?

**Workaround:**
Definitely not the perfect solution but as a workaround, try the below code and see if this works out for you:

```
<a href="/about#top" class="a-color">
    <small>About</small>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding you don't want page to reload after user clicks on any link on your page, you only want some area should get refreshed right ?

In that case you can use templates, configure route according to states and by click on link you can change template by $state.go.