# Why does href take me to the bottom of the page it links to instead of the top?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have several relative links in the footer of my home page which link to other pages in my website.  Looks like this:

```
<footer>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/howto">How to</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**I want the links to place the user at the top of the pages which the links lead to, but instead they place the user in the middle or towards the bottom** of the page in a seemingly random manner. All of the links seem to be doing this except for the navigation links which are at the very top of the page.  It seems like the links are trying to take me to the same location (as the link) on the page they link to.

It might help to mention that angular.js is handling the routing in this app.

Comment: You need to provide more code to reproduce your issue. Please, read this => [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try "/howto/#" and "/contact/#".

Comment: Hello, DC3314!  What robo007 is more trying to state is that your code "should" work as you explained based only on the code you have posted.  Your issue is caused by something that is not included in your question.

Comment: The footer is as simple as what I've put in my question.  I don't know what other code to add.  CSS maybe?  By the way, in response to Ealon - thanks for the suggestion.  It works the first time I click on the link, but not after that.

Comment: I was finally just able to find someone who asked this same question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234366/my-anchor-link-wont-start-at-top-of-page?rq=1 .   This person provided even less code than me but funnily enough got several upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently angular's `<ng-view></ng-view>` maintains the scroll position after switching between views.  Adding the `autoscroll=true` attribute fixes this problem.  So now I have `<ng-view autoscroll="true"></ng-view>`.  Vidyadhar  provided the answer here: [My Anchor link won't start at top of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234366/my-anchor-link-wont-start-at-top-of-page?rq=1)